# Sum of first ten numbers squared help in Python

Tags: python

```
for code in range(1,11) :
    a = code**2
    b = sum(a)
    print(b)
```

I am trying to find the sum of the squares of the first 10 numbers.

1^2 + 2^2 + ... + 10^2 = 385

But my program will not allow the line `b = sum(a)`. Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Your algorithm is way off, leading to things like trying to add up all of one number (which doesn't make sense to the interpreter, and therefore causes an error). I recommend taking a look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in a for loop, you'd need to add to your b variable each time through that for loop, like so:

```
b = 0
for code in range(1,11):
    a = code**2
    b = b + a
print(b)
```

You can also use python's list comprehensions to do this in one line, and skip the for loop:

```
b = sum([a**2 for a in range(1, 11)])
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) does not work like this. This function accept an iterable and compute the sum of each elements.

This is why you have to set your `for` loop **inside** the `sum()`, and this is called a "generator expression".

```
b = sum(code**2 for code in range(1,11))
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum function takes a sequence as an argument.  You don't need a loop if you use it.  Also, the exponentiation operator in python is ** not ^, so the you can say

```
print(sum([code**2 for code in range(1,11)])
```